# Change expression in body of elisp function with advice

Tags: emacs, elisp, defadvice

How do you match a specific expression in the body on elisp function when adding advice?  Specifically, in the following example, I would like to advise the function to use `find-file-noselect` in place of `find-file`, ie.
the line `(find-file path)` would be in effect `(find-file-noselect path)`.

```
(defun tst-fun (path line column)
  (find-file path)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (forward-line (1- line))
  (forward-char column))

;; not sure how to structure this
(defadvice tst-fun (around noselect activate)
  (find-file-noselect (ad-get-arg 0))
  ad-do-it)
```

I would rather have it as `ad-add-function`, but am trying to just get this working first.

Comment: Advice is run before, after, or instead of the advised function, but it doesn't modify how the original function itself works.

Comment: @Barmar so, there is no way to do something like set `ad-do-it` to `(cdr ad-do-it)`?

Comment: That will call `tst-fun`, and then return the `cdr` of whatever it returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could temporarily redefine `find-file` as `find-file-noselect` in the advice.

```
(require 'cl)
(defadvice tst-fun (around noselect activate)
  (flet ((find-file (&rest args)
           (apply 'find-file-noselect args)))
    ad-do-it))
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no way to do that. Some other Lisp dialects had `:INSIDE` advice, where you could advise `find-file` only inside `tst-fun`, but Elisp doesn't have this.

Comment: In "modern" Elisp, this would look like: `(require 'cl-lib) (advice-add 'tst-fun :around (lambda (orig &rest args) (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'find-file) #'find-file-noselect)) (apply orig args))`.